# Cocoa WebKit/WebView delegate for location change? (User clicked link, javascript action, etc)

Tags: cocoa, webkit, webview

I have added a WebView to a Cocoa application and I'm trying to figure out which delegate I can use to detect when navigation changes (user clicks a link, or javascript fires to change the location, etc).

The [WebView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) contains four delegates (WebFrameLoadDelegate Protocol Reference, WebPolicyDelegate Protocol Reference, WebResourceLoadDelegate Protocol Reference and WebUIDelegate Protocol Reference) and I have looked at each of these, but I cannot seem to find how to detect this. Am I missing something blatantly obvious or is there no way to get this?

tldr - Trying to figure out how I can set a delegate to get an event when the WebView is changing URL. (Specifically I need to know what the new URL is).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using WebKit (i.e. MacOS X) then probably the best place to track requests is in `webView:identifierForInitialRequest:fromDataSource:`, although `webView:resource:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:fromDataSource:` is also good, and has the advantage of allowing you to modify the request.

As with iOS, you can use `[request URL]`.

Set this via `[webView setResourceLoadDelegate:self];`.

The resource load delegate (as above) gives better options to handle the request, in my opinion, than the policy delegate methods.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you implement these two `WebPolicyDelegate` methods:

```
-webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:
-webView:decidePolicyForNewWindowAction:request:newFrameName:decisionListener:
```

That will tell you the new URL being navigated to, but also give you a chance to change the default behaviour. e.g. you may not WebKit attempting to open new windows.

Answer (score -1):

Implement

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    return YES;
}
```

and test the navigation type within the body.  Your class needs to be set as the delegate of the web view, and implement the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol.  The URL can be obtained from the request:

```
[request URL]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this Mac development using the WebView class and not the iOS UIWebView class.

Comment: Leaving this (incorrect, for this situation) answer, as iOS programmers may arrive here with this exact question.