# How do I allow downloads from a WebView using the standard download system on a Mac app?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-lion

I am building a mac app and would like to able to include the ability to browse the web and download files from the sites using the standard downloads system like you see when using safari.

At the moment when I click a link to a .zip or .nzb in the app it does nothing! Is there a way of allowing this from the app?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: @(Will Roberts)-I am trying the same, but not able to download anything.Can you tell me how to achieve this. I am not able to understand Rob Keniger post.

Answer (score 11):

The download manager in Safari is implemented by Safari, not by WebKit, so you don't get that functionality "for free", just the tools to build it.

In order to be able to download files, you need to assign an object as the `WebPolicyDelegate` of the `WebView` and implement the `webView:decidePolicyForMIMEType:request:frame:decisionListener:` delegate method.

In that method, you must call one of the `WebPolicyDecisionListener` protocol methods on the object that is passed as the `decisionlistener` parameter to the method. The three `WebPolicyDecisionListener` protocol methods are `ignore`, `use` or `download`. For any MIME types that you want to download, you must call `download` on the object passed as the listener parameter:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView 
   decidePolicyForMIMEType:(NSString *)type 
                   request:(NSURLRequest *)request 
                     frame:(WebFrame *)frame 
          decisionListener:(id < WebPolicyDecisionListener >)listener
{
    if([type isEqualToString:@"application/zip"])
    {
        [listener download];
    }
    //just ignore all other types; the default behaviour will be used
}
```

You then need to assign an object as the download delegate of your `WebView`. This object will be sent all of the [`NSURLDownloadDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLDownloadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol messages as well as the [`WebDownload`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebDownload_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
 delegate messages. You can use these messages to choose where the file is downloaded, as well as to implement a download manager UI like Safari.

Comment: You sound like you've built this component.  Any hint as to how to "catch all" *files*?  Or, how to catch the inverse - "web pages" that should be loaded in the browser?

Comment: Or perhaps this isn't even the right question, as some files (images for example) the user may want to download at times and other times view in-browser.  Further still, there are often "hints" in href links that the item should be downloaded instead of viewed.  Hmm... sounds like its own question...

Comment: [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)[[frame provisionalDataSource] response] allHeaderFields]

Check for the values "Content-Disposition" in this dictionary.
this will help you identify the download items.

Comment: @SG1: You should be able to show what can be viewed with this code:

 if ([[webView class] canShowMIMEType:type]) // might be a subtype of WebView
 {
  [listener use]; // render things that can be shown
 }
 else
 {
  [listener download]; // download everything else
 }

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head I would think you could implement the WebView's delegates to detect when a user clicks on a link - then check the extension and if it's not html/php/whatever then manually download the file yourself

Here's a link to a question (and answer) for how to capture the link pressing:

[Cocoa WebKit/WebView delegate for location change? (User clicked link, javascript action, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778455/cocoa-webkit-webview-delegate-for-location-change-user-clicked-link-javascrip)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem with this is that the links that I am trying to click have no extension. Example: http://******.com/download.php?id=1170176&nozip=1&cat=36.

Comment: ok then how do you identify which links are for download and which are for display?

Comment: At the moment I do a check that if the url contains a certain term it is indeed a download link therefore x needs to be done with it!

Comment: You shouldn't use file extensions anyway. The HTTP header will include a mime type for the data it returns, you should key off that.

Comment: if you capture the link you can just check if the link has that term and do the download - but bames53 is right it is better to test the HTTP headers of the file

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to open the link in external browser. And the file will be downloaded using external browser's download manager.

Sample code in Swift 2.2 with XCode 7.3:

```
func webView(webView: WebView!, decidePolicyForNavigationAction actionInformation: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, request: NSURLRequest!, frame: WebFrame!, decisionListener listener: WebPolicyDecisionListener!) {
    let url = request.URL!.absoluteString
    if url.hasSuffix(".zip") || url.hasSuffix(".nzb") {
        listener.ignore()
        NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().openURL(request.URL!)
    } else {
        listener.use()
    }
}
```

PS. method above comes from `WebPolicyDelegate`.